# In Windows XP, how to run a exe on some computer in LAN and make it run on that computer by using a batch file in my computer?

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, batch-file, exe, lan

The problem goes this way. We are developing an application which is taking huge time to run and also we have limited license problem.

So we have purchased a new computer with a very high configuration. Now this new PC is in LAN and all the 4 developers should use this PC for running the application.

**The scenario:**
The developer has all the files ready to be run. Now he copies all the files into a shared directory on the new PC. 
Then he clicks a batch file in the local computer which has to call the exe on the other computer and run the tool on other computer. After the tool finishes running, it puts the result in a text file which can be taken by user later. 
In this way, the tool runs very fast and also the license issue is solved.

**Problem definition:**
Typically whenever we double click an exe on shared computer, the exe runs locally on my PC which I dont want to happen.

**How do I call an exe on some other computer on LAN and make it run on that computer?
 Is it possible in Windows XP? 

If yes, how do I go about it?**

Note: I have to finally have a simple batch file which will be clicked on the local computer and it runs the exe on other computer.

**EDIT1 :** 
I found some things in internet like 
WMIC utility
PsExec utility - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553 
Is any of the above useful to my problem?

Comment: If you were in *nix, I'd say SSH. It might still be applicable on Windows, but I've never done it.

Comment: @Thanatos - Actually I should be able to do the entire thing by just clicking on a batch file in local computer :( SSH will be one more utility rite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark Russinovich's PsExec is what you want. You will need administrator privileges on the target machine. For example:

```
PSEXEC \\othermachine z:\program.exe
```

(You may also want to specify arguments for username/password - the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) gives all the options you can use.)

Comment: I am getting access denied. I tried the following command PSEXEC \\10.0.59.84 -u admin -p admin "c:\program files\internet explorer\iexp
lore.exe"   What might be the reason? I have disabled firewall on the target PC also!!

Comment: Usually on windows the admin account is called "Administrator" (not "admin") - can you connect to the computer using that username/password? (e.g. try: `start \\10.0.59.84` and use the same username/password). Also there may be issues with spaces in the filename - try just running "iexplore.exe" (no full path) - if it's in the `PATH` on the target machine it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](http://lifehacker.com/5547714/launch-applications-remotely-with-dropbox-and-autohotkey) "solution" (more of a hack than anything - but a clever one) could help you?

Comment: Hey actually I should be able to do the entire thing by just clicking on a batch file in local computer. I cant run any gui tools :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is [rsh](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rsh.mspx?mfr=true).  This depends on the Windows version that you have.

Comment: It has to work on Windows XP !! So rsh wont be useful for me !!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise writing a little script in any language you like (although I'd recommend Python since I've done something similar). This script should run as a service on the shared PC and listen on the network for a particular command on the network which you send from another Python script on the developer's PC.
This causes the script on the shared PC to run your executable. Since you also have a shared directory on the shared PC it should be easy to script the copying of the files too.

Comment: Do you mean we write a service which continously listens? Something like a server running which listens for http requests ?

Comment: Yes, although it doesn't have to be http. You could choose anything you like, or just write your own simple protocol to listen on a specific port and react to simple commands (for example, if you want it to behave in different ways, just have an ASCII letter for each command). You should consider security issues of course.